# facing issues in connecting to Teradata via python using teradatasql Module

Tags: python-3.x, teradata, teradatasql

Code:

```
import teradatasql

ExecutionContext = teradatasql.connect (host="xxxx", user="xxxx", password="xxx")

def select(exec_context: ExecutionContext):
    try:
        conn =exec_context.connection
        curs = conn.cursor()
        curs.execute(f"""
          sel top 10 * from dbc.tablesv
        """)
        curs.execute("COMMIT")
        curs.close()

    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception (str(e))
```

Error:

```
python3 box_code.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/box_code.py", line 9, in <module>
    ExecutionContext = teradatasql.connect (host="xx", user="xxx", password="xxx")
  File "/Users/xx/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/teradatasql/__init__.py", line 138, in __init__
    goside = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(sLibPathName)
  File "/Users/xx/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/Users/xx/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/Users/xx/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/teradatasql/teradatasql.dylib, 0x0006): tried: '/Users/xx/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/teradatasql/teradatasql.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
```

machine: MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021), Apple M1 Pro Chip

Comment: The current version of `teradatasql` does not natively support M1 (arm64e) architecture. You would need to run an x86_64 version of Python under Rosetta.

Comment: Hi could you formulate your question a bit better. Have a look at the guidance on How to Ask a Good Question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , in particular note a good question will _Introduce the problem before posting any code_.  Your question would also benefit encapsulating the code blocks in tick marks \`\`\` before and after the code block. Have a look at the formating help also https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Looks like the version of teradatasql==20.0.0.1 is working well (without rosetta).
https://support.teradata.com/knowledge?id=kb_article_view&sys_kb_id=50776fb787b5d9901aec53d73cbb357b